# How best to combine two series of geographic coordinate pairs outside of any GIS software?

Tags: geo

I have two series of points (latitude & longitude) that represent a vehicle's path, but each series comes from a different receiver with different (complementary) data. I want to combine these into a single composite series, preserving all original values but merged as one. Importantly, I need them to be in the correct order. The catch is that I don't have timestamps, so I can't simply union and sort. Points *are*, however, in chronological order.

Is there an established algorithm that can be used to merge two paths fairly accurately (eg, accounting for the heading of the vehicle, arbitrary and overlapping paths it might take, etc.)?

Comment: Interesting problem. Pretty sure you will have to write something yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is any established algorithm. Gave this some thought and here is how I would have approached this. Say you have two series `S1 = [P0, P1, P2, ....]` and `S2 = [P0, P1, P2, ....]`. You parameterize each series with **cumulative** distance from some fixed point. Call that `P_ref`. And now this cumulative distance serves as a proxy for time-stamps that are not there. This also works for overlapping trajectories as even if two points coincide, the cumulative distance parameter for each of those two points would be different.

And once you have an consistent independent identifier between those two series, merging them together is straightforward.

Comment: Great suggestion! It's actually quite elegant. The only catch is to determine where that reference point is. If `P_ref` starts at or very near `S1[P0]`, then `S1[P0]` would be deemed the starting point; however, if `S2[P0]` is in reality the chronologically first point, it would need a negative distance to the reference to indicate that it's earlier in time. Perhaps starting with the assumption that `S1[P0]` is 'first' and walking along `S1` could afford some ability to do that.

Comment: Yes. The tricky bit here is to find an appropriate `P_ref`. You could sort of examine the direction of vector `S1[P0, P1]` and `S2[P0, P1]`. In an ideal world, they should both converge to the same starting point which ends up being `P_ref`. That is, dot product of vector `[P_ref, S[P0]]` for each series with `[P0, P1]` is positive.